# If $\lim f(x)$ can theoretically be anywhere on the interval $0$ up to and including $\infty$, is the interval written $(0,\infty]$?

Tags: notation

Let's take $f(x)=a^x+b$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b\in\mathbb R^+$. clearly $L=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)>0$, but is the interval written $L\in(0,\infty)$ because limits only approach infinity or is $L\in(0,\infty]$ because infinity is one of the values $L$ can take? I can't find an example of this one way or another.

Comment: You mean starting from $0$ (including it) to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @Spectre, I didn't really pay attention to the $0$ side, I'm more worried about whether $\infty$ is able to be expressed as explicitly a part of the interval without having to write it elsewhere.

Comment: Look at @BrianMoehring's answer.

Comment: What he said is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to write $L = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$, then it would be false to state $L \in (0,\infty)$.

You would need to be able to write $L \in (0,\infty]$, but we also need to keep in mind that $L = \infty$ isn't a real number, so this only makes sense in the context of the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: Thanks for helping me learn, sir !

Answer (score 1):

Technically the answer is neither.

When we say $x \in (0, \infty)$, that notation is only valid when $x$ is a number.

When we say $\lim_{x\to\infty} = \infty$, that does not mean the limit is the number $\infty$. It means $\forall N> 0: \exists M> 0:$ if $x > M,$ then $f(x) > N$.

However you could extend the definition of the bracket $[a,b]$ notation to allow for such limits that do not take any value.